# Use Formula variable in regex, filter XML - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to be able to use a variable from the formula to filter tags from an XML document at a URL specified in the formula. This is working, but I am having trouble adding a second formula variable to change the tag regex as needed.
in the Google sheet, i am calling the function with =importWebsite("url.com","ReqID")

```
function importWebsite(url,xmlTag) {
  var found, html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    const regexpTemplate = '/<xmlTag>(.*)<\\/xmlTag>/gi';
    var regexpString = regexpTemplate.replace(/xmlTag/g, xmlTag); //trying to swap the regex content with the variable xmlTag
    if (html) content = html.match(regexpString);
  }
  return content;

}
```

using html.match with the regex `/<ReqID>(.*)<\/ReqID>/gi` works as expected, but I wanted to be able to change the tag I am matching based on the formula variable.

working code without second variable:

```
function importWebsite(url) {
  var found, html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    if (html) content = html.match(/<ReqID>(.*)<\/ReqID>/gi);
  }
  return content;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out!

I did not compile the RegEx before inserting it. Now, this looks at the XML at the URL and pulls the tags that match the content.

```
function importWebsite(url,xmlTag) {
  
  var found, html, content = '';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  if (response) {
    html = response.getContentText();
    const regexpTemplate = '<xmlTag>(.*)<\\/xmlTag>';
    var regexpString = regexpTemplate.replace(/xmlTag/g, xmlTag)
    var regexp =  new RegExp(regexpString, 'gi');
    if (html) content = html.match(regexp);
  }
return content;
}
```

I also went ahead and added a section to remove the tags since what I was interested in pulling was the content.
for this, replace `return content;` with the below. There is probably a way to do it with lookbehind/lookahead regex but alas my brain hurts.

```
  var prerem = [ ...new Set(content.map(xmlcont => {
   return xmlcont.split('>')[1]
}))]
  var postrem = [ ...new Set(prerem.map(xmlcont => {
   return xmlcont.split('</')[0]
}))]

var newcontent = postrem;
return newcontent;
```